# User of Razor on an MVC 2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I am new to MVC so I am asking this question,

I have visual studio 2010 version 4.0.30319 SP1 Rel already installed and currently we are using MVC2 . I have been asked to you MVC3 razor view engine. So in order to get that I am assuming, I need to install this

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=&appid=MVC3

My question is, can I start developing using MVC3 in my existing project which is currently in MVC2 ? I dont want to modify the existing code or upgrade to MVC3. Is it possible ?

Is there any other thing that I need to download and install. What are the changes that I need to make in my web.config file or any other file to make this MVC2 project run ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This isnt something iv'e done before but the link below will make the appropriate referential changes in order to create razor view pages.

[MVC 3 Conversion](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008)

However there was a link I found on that page in the comments provided by mpost dated july 15h 2011 to a exe conversion tool. Would be interested to see how much success, if any you get from it.

[Razor view converter](http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/)